# Generar números aletorios **reales** entre 1 y 100 en c#

Tags: c#

me gustaría que me facilitéis alguna metodología para generar números reales aleatorios entre 1 y 100 dentro de un array, el método random.NextDouble(),devuelve valores entre 0.0 y 1.0. Lo tengo con enteros:

```
    var seed = Environment.TickCount;
    var random = new Random(seed);
    
    double[] reales = new double[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < reales.Length; i++)
    {
        reales[i] = random.Next(1,50);
        Console.WriteLine(reales[i]);
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué `random.Next(1,100)` no te vale?

Comment: porque los añade como enteros y el ejercicio pide números reales

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> el método `random.NextDouble()`, devuelve valores entre 0.0 y 1.0. Lo tengo con enteros

Por magia y gracia de las matemáticas, si multiplicas el resultado de `random.NextDouble()` por cien, tendrás valores entre 0.0 y 100.0. Si quieres valores entre 1.0 y 100.00 multiplica `random.NextDouble()` por noventa y nueve y súmale uno:

```
var seed = Environment.TickCount;
var random = new Random(seed);

double[] reales = new double[10];
for (int i = 0; i < reales.Length; i++)
{
    reales[i] = 1.0 + (random.NextDouble() * 99.0);
    Console.WriteLine(reales[i]);
}
```

Comment: jajaja gracias no se como no he caido...

Comment: O, tal vez, `random.NextDouble()` por noventa y nueve, y le sumas `random.NextDouble()`, que es entre cero y uno. ;)

Comment: @Arriel no, eso daría un resultado entre 0 y 100.

Comment: Yup yup yup... Cierto